# Manchester Airport UK - Where can one sleep on a chair on the air side after arrival in the middle of the night?

Tags: airports, sleeping, man

Manchester Airport UK goes to sleep at night. All public transport stops and all car rental depots are closed. If my flight arrives, say, at 2 AM, and I have only a small personal bag and no luggage to collect, where in the airport can I sleep for around 3 hours in a chair while waiting for the first train or bus? This would preferably be on the air side, where people off the street have no access.  I can think of 3 options:

1. Between the disembarkation gate and passport control
2. Between passport control and the luggage pickup area
3. In the luggage pickup area itself. There are some comfortable benches in that area but I don't know if it's permissible to to sleep there.

Comment: Are you sure those parts of the airport are open in the night? It may well be that they move everybody out onto the streets as soon as they can pick up their luggage.

Comment: See Sleeping in Airports guide, this is the *gold standard* for this https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/manchester-airport-guide.htm

Comment: Which terminal https://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/flight-information/which-terminal/?  In T1, IIRC, Immigration and baggage pickup are separated by nothing more than a flight of steps down to the luggage carousels, which rules out option 2 if that’s the arrival terminal for your flight. The location of Manchester airport isn’t terribly likely to attract ‘people off the street’ IMHO - there’s really nothing much around it other than motorway/dual carriageway access roads, hotels and the bus/rail station

Answer (score 9):

The first of your two options are not possible I think. It's all corridors without anwyhere to pause or anything to sit on, and I suspect if you attempted it you may be moved on by security.

Baggage claim may be possible, there's normally very little staff activity in the area.

Landside has limited facilities, but there are areas of seating in most departure areas before security. There's also several hotels on site, and if you are staying in Manchester, it's a fairly short journey to the city centre, and a "private hire" cab jourmey would typically cost you £25-£30. The "first" train after a 2AM arrival is not that long away, tomorrow for example there is an 03:59 departure.

I think there may also be some seating in the "skybridge" section above the station, or nearby, but I can't find photos to confirm.